# Class hierarchy and inheritance (unclear task)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, hierarchy

I got problem with understanding the task:

> "Consider the class Bicycle. Given your knowledge of some common components 
>   of bicycle, show a class hierarchy in which the class Bicycle inherits from other 
>   classes, which, in turn, inherit from yet other classes. Discuss the instantiation of 
>   various objects of class Bicycle. Discuss inheritance from class Bicycle for other 
>   closely related derived classes. Write a program that demonstrate proposed by you hierarchy."

It's so imprecise, that I completly don't know what do I have to show, especially that I've already did one task with using showing inheritance and using virtual classes.

Could u give me some examples how do you understand that task?

Cheers.

Comment: Try placing `is a` before and after Bicycle. `X is a bicycle` and `A bicycle is a Y`.

Comment: This question is only about inheitence, not composition, but you will probably also eventually want to place `has a` after bicycle and all it's related classes to discover what a bicycle is made up of.

Comment: So something like writing class deriving from bicycle and another class, which from bicycle derives?

Comment: not a question for this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* a bad question: because although it's asking about inheritance (for example, "a bicycle **isa** road vehicle"), it also says "your knowledge of some common components of bicycle" (for example, "a bicycle **has** two wheels"), which seems to me to be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Maybe they meant classes like `RoadVehicle` > `MotorlessVehicle` > `Bicycle`

Comment: @Angew Road vehicles have a lot of common/basic behaviour, e.g. both bikes and cars must obey traffic laws.

Comment: I was referring to the component part of the question, e.g. a bike has no motor and is one-tracked.